# Can I create a custom biome with no floor for my datapack?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-data-packs

I've been looking into custom world generation recently and I found out that you can create custom biomes and have them generate in the world. I was wondering if it was at all possible to use this to create a biome with no floor at all. Like just a hole that drops into the void. I know I could use custom worldgen settings to create floating islands, but then I couldn't have stuff like custom particles, fog, or water. I've tried using custom surface builders, but I don't think they're powerful enough.

Is it possible to have a custom biome override the world generation and just be a huge hole?

Comment: Update: Using custom carvers I am able to remove the vast majority of the stone (aside from a few stray blocks here and there which I don't mind), however there is still a bedrock floor. I could remove it in the world generation but I'd have to figure out how to add it back for all the rest of the biomes.

Comment: Can you set the blocks in the biome to all be air?

Comment: You can do that for the surface blocks, but underneath will still be stone.

Answer (score -1):

You could generate the world as a void through the game itself by going into more world options → World type superflat → customize → presets → void and generating your world like that and you could use world edit to change the biome of specific blocks.

Comment: That’s not at all what I’m looking for. I don’t want the entire world to be void, just one specific naturally-occurring  biome